# Can't see Physics tab in Properties Panel in Blender

Tags: properties

[image]

**strong text**

I have Windows 7.Blender version is 2.79 and I can't see any tab after the wrench icon in Properties Panel.

Answer (score 2):

Hover with your mouse over the top, last icon of the property list. Now, roll the mouse wheel, the rest of the icons will display.
You can also do that on all main menus at the bottom of each 3d window to see the rest of the options menus.

Comment: Oh boy ! I was suffering.Thanks a ton! Total noob here.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can stretch the panel with <kbd>LMB 🖱</kbd> when you see white ↔ after you hover over the panel's edge. This way you can see all of them all the time. And the wheel just scrolls the tabs. The way given above is useful with multiple editors open.

Comment: Really grateful for the response!